# Can i change type of a field for already created pdf?

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-form

I have already created pdf, where I have field called `Name` which is of type `String`.

How can I change this field type to `List` like [here](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter08/choice_fields.pdf)?

Here is example how to add field type `List` for new PDF file:

```
cell.setCellEvent(new ChoiceFields(4));
```

Comment: Why don't you change your PDF creation process to create fields of type `List` to begin with?

Comment: @AlexisPigeon Yeah, i can do it. But for example if i have large amount already created pdfs. And i need to add for all `Name` fields `List` functionality.